# Cabal update failure (return code: -9)

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I got that error when trying to use `cabal update`

below were the results of `cabal update -v3`

```
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Sending:
GET /packages/archive/00-index.tar.gz HTTP/1.1
Host: hackage.haskell.org
User-Agent: cabal-install/1.16.0.2
Creating new connection to hackage.haskell.org
Received:
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Thu, 13 Nov 2014 00:14:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Location: /packages/index.tar.gz
Content-Length: 0
301 - redirect
Redirecting to http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/index.tar.gz ...
Sending:
GET /packages/index.tar.gz HTTP/1.1
Host: hackage.haskell.org
User-Agent: cabal-install/1.16.0.2
Recovering connection to hackage.haskell.org
Received:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Thu, 13 Nov 2014 00:14:21 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-gzip
Content-Length: 8090775
Connection: keep-alive
Content-MD5: bae2f93619ba845eff2f3bd544714c2c
ETag: "bae2f93619ba845eff2f3bd544714c2c"
Last-Modified: Wed, 12 Nov 2014 23:04:10 GMT
Downloaded to /root/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/00-index.tar.gz
Updating the index cache file...
cabal update: /usr/hs/tools/cabal-1.16.0.2 failure (return code=-9)
```

haskell was installed from [justhub](http://justhub.org)

Does anyone have any idea why it failed? I looked for the return code of `-9` but there's no information.

**Update**

Thanks Reid (and user5402),

Checked the dmesg and that's definitely because it's out of memory

```
Out of memory: Kill process 32626 (cabal-1.16.0.2) score 711 or sacrifice child
```

Will upgrade the machine and try again, not sure how much would cabal-install need though, I'm on a 512MB RAM system

Comment: I would try running the command with `strace -f` to trace all system calls including forked children and look for a failed system call near the end of the output. It is also possible `return code=-9` refers to the exit status of a child process.

Comment: -9 probably means a child process died to SIGKILL, which in turn was probably sent by the OOM killer. Are you on a low memory machine? Check the output of dmesg to see whether there are any relevant messages there.

Comment: I also had the same problem with a low ram VPS on Terminal.com, just 256 MB and the process kept getting killed. Cranking RAM up to 1600 MB and the update completed fairly swiftly.

Answer (score 2):

The value -9 probably means a child process died to SIGKILL, which in turn was probably sent by the OOM killer. Checking the output of `dmesg` can confirm this. If that's the case, one needs to turn up the RAM available. (based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899426/cabal-update-failure-return-code-9/36110639?noredirect=1#comment42379652_26899426)).

Comment: An out-of-memory error appears to have caused this same problem for me --- with an exit code of 137.

Answer (score 1):

512Mb of RAM is not enough. Instead of upgrading machine you can enable swap.

On ubuntu do following steps:

```
sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

It will add you 4G swap file, that will prevent killing from OS.